# Scrape website that has endless scrolling in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, screen-scraping

I have encountered a website that has an endless scroll when navigating to the website. That means when you manually scroll down and without any clicks the web page is loading automatically ..
This is my try

```
Sub Test()
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://shopee.com.my/shop/145423/followers/?__classic__=1"
        Do: DoEvents: Loop While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
        Dim html As Object
        Set html = .document
        Dim elemRect As IHTMLRect: Set elemRect = html.querySelector(".loading-text") 'myDiv.getBoundingClientRect
    Do Until elemRect.bottom > 0
        .ParentWindow.scrollBy 0, 10000
        Set elemRect = html.querySelector(".loading-text")
    Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

I need to know if it is possible to scrape such webpages and if yes how can this process be controlled?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183215/handling-lazy-loading-webpages-using-vba

Comment: In the code found in the link `Loop Until NoChangesCount = 5` why exactly 5? Will this work till all the data is loaded?

Comment: Hiya, What do you think? Did you read the comments for that line?

Comment: This works for scrolling for 5 times. But what if I need to loop till the whole page is laoded or this is impossible?

Comment: If the scrolling is "endless" then how would YOU define "whole page"?

Comment: @braX I am not sure if it is endless or not. I am just trying to learn about such an issue.

Comment: It is a constant that you can think of as retries. If you have scrolled that  number of times and there are no more target elements you assume all items retrieved. Whether this is arbitrary or evidence based I don't know. It makes sense to try a few times at least. Btw it is lazy loading.

Comment: Standard technique for these pages, scroll a distance/bring something into viewport - do a target count, scroll again do a count rinse repeat.....stop when no change in target count (or no change 5 times!)

Comment: When navigating to `Network` section in developer tools, I noticed that url `https://shopee.com.my/shop/145423/followers/?offset=40&limit=20&offset_of_offset=0&_=1610816895131`, I think this offset parameter can be played with. In that case can it be possible to use XMLHTTP?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=shopee.com.my